# Stage camera won't move

Tags: java, libgdx

In my game, I have my objects represented as a actors, thus all of the game objects would be on a Stage. For some reason when I try to move the Stage's camera around, it won't work, or actually it doesn't seem to work. I have added a game Actor to the location of 0,0. When I translate the camera's position around, the Actor still stays at the bottom left corner, despite when I log the camera's position, it shows that the camera has moved.

```
public class Striker extends Actor {

    private Sprite img;

    private World worldRef;
    private Body body;


    //constructor
    public Striker(float size, float x, float y, World world) {
        img = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Striker.png")));
        //mains the aspect size ratio
        img.setSize((275f / 300f) * size, size);
        img.setPosition(x, y);

        worldRef = world;

        //set up the physics
        BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
        bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
        bodyDef.position.set(x,y);
        body = world.createBody(bodyDef);

    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        img.draw(batch);
    }

    @Override
    public void act(float delta) {
        super.act(delta);
    }

    @Override
    public float getX() {
        return body.getPosition().x;
    }

    @Override
    public float getY() {
        return body.getPosition().y;
    }

    @Override
    public float getWidth() {
        return img.getWidth();
    }

    @Override
    public float getHeight() {
        return img.getHeight();
    }
}
```

The results of the 2 logs show that the camera's positions have moved, but it doesn't look like it.

```
public class StrikerScreen implements Screen {

    public static float WIDTH = 1920;
    public static float HEIGHT = 1080;
    public static float PPM = 200;

    private Launcher launcherRef;

    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private FitViewport viewport;

    private World world;
    private Box2DDebugRenderer debugRenderer;

    private Striker striker;

    private Stage gameStage;

    //constructor
    public StrikerScreen(Launcher launcher) {
        launcherRef = launcher;

        world = new World(new Vector2(0, -9.8f), true);
        debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();

        gameStage = new Stage();
        camera = (OrthographicCamera) gameStage.getCamera();
        viewport = new FitViewport(WIDTH / PPM, HEIGHT / PPM, gameStage.getCamera());
        viewport.apply();

        gameStage.setViewport(viewport);
        striker = new Striker(160f / PPM, 0, 0, world);
        gameStage.addActor(striker);

        gameStage.getCamera().translate(viewport.getWorldWidth() / 2f, 500f, 0);
        viewport.apply();
        camera.update();

        Gdx.app.log("StrikerScreen.java", "Camera position: " + gameStage.getCamera().position.toString());
        Gdx.app.log("StrikerScreen.java", "Camera size: " + gameStage.getCamera().viewportWidth + ", " + gameStage.getCamera().viewportHeight);

    }

    @Override
    public void show() {

    }

    public void update(float delta) {
        world.step(1 / 30f, 6, 2);
        gameStage.act(delta);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        update(delta);
        debugRenderer.render(world, camera.combined);
        gameStage.draw();

    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        viewport.update(width, height, true);
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you posted, the only times you move the camera are in the StrikerScreen constructor where you explicitly translate it, and in the `resize` method, where you have called `viewport.update(width, height, true);` Passing `true` to `viewport.update` tells it to move the camera to where (0, 0) is in the bottom left of corner of the viewport. Since `resize` is automatically called when you set your screen to this screen, that is the most recent position you have set the camera to.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot that when I update the viewport, I change the camera's position.